# A basic question on derivative

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a differentiable function $f$ on $[a, b]$ with $f(a) = 0$. Let $x_0 \in [a, b]$. Now for any $x$ such that $a \leq x \leq x_{0}$, can we say anything about the quantity
$$
\left\lvert\,\frac{f(x)- f(a)}
              {x_0 - a}\,\right\rvert\ ?
$$
Can it be made equal to some derivative?

Comment: I guess you are looking for [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable, you will find $f'(a)$ = $\lim_{x \to a}$ $\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$

Comment: Is that an absolute value bar? If so, think positive thoughts!

Comment: @SecretMath: no there is no mod in MVT. Also the numerator should have been $f(x_0)$ rather than $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{{\rm e}^{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$

$$
\exists\ \mu\ \ni\quad \verts{{\rm f}\pars{x} - {\rm f}\pars{a} \over x_{0} - a}
=
\verts{{\rm f}\pars{x_{0}} - {\rm f}\pars{a} \over x_{0} - a}\
\verts{{\rm f}\pars{x} \over {\rm f}\pars{x_{0}}}
=
{\rm f}'\pars{\mu}\verts{{\rm f}\pars{x} \over {\rm f}\pars{x_{0}}}\,,
\qquad
a < \mu < x_{0}
$$

Comment: $(f(x_0) - f(a)) \cdot \frac{f(x)}{f(x_0)} = f(x) - f(a)$ ?

Comment: @SecretMath Notice that $\large{\rm f}\left(a\right) = 0$.